# Node.JS web worker memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, web-worker

I've got a Node.JS application that spawns a number of Web Workers.

I'm seeing what looks like a slow memory leak, but I don't think it's my code. Even if I comment out the code entirely, and I just have a web worker that accepts messages and returns nothing, the memory leak still occurs!

The problem seems to be that I'm sending large messages. Often they are 1MB of JSON or more. Eventually the Workers balloon up from 6MB up to 25MB, and I'm not sure it will stop there.

Is this a known problem with Node.JS web workers? Is there a workaround?

The workers are managed with a pool abstraction. Should I just kill them off and spawn new ones from time to time?

EDIT: I'm thinking maybe it's the particular pool library I used,[backgrounder](https://github.com/jolira/backgrounder). No obvious culprits in the code, though.

Comment: backgrounder hasn't been updated in two years, what functionality is it providing you beyond what require('child_process').fork does?

Comment: very few of these libraries have been updated recently. But it's just providing an abstraction so I can spawn many workers, get health checks, terminate, and otherwise send messages to a non-loaded worker, without managing that in the app.